# IPhone: Core Animation: expand a view in y axis

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I am learning Core Animation and as per my task I have to expand/collapse a layer in y-axis linearly I have following piece of code

```
CABasicAnimation *shrinkAnimation;
shrinkAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"]; //use transform instead of bounds.size
shrinkAnimation.repeatCount = 1;
shrinkAnimation.autoreverses = NO;
[shrinkAnimation setDuration:1.5];
shrinkAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]; 
shrinkAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DScale(myView.layer.transform, 1, 0.1, 1.0)];
[myView.layer addAnimation:shrinkAnimation forKey:@"bounds.size"];
```

but the problem here is the layer contracts/expands from both the ends simultaneously, can you help me to get it expand/collapse in one direction.

Thanks in advance

Regards

Ankit

Answer (score 0):

set the `anchor point` of your layer to `0,0` or `1,1` or some other values, to make the edge you want won't move.

```
myView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0);
```

Comment: where the statements did you put, you should put it before the layer add animation statements.

Comment: yupp did that but when I do that no animation takes place at all the layer just shift from one position to another

Comment: @AnkitSachan changement of anchor point is affect the view position. so, put the anchorPointer set statement just after the alloc-init, and set the view frame to adjust to the position. the animation should work.

Comment: man this animation is for a UI Element more precisely a UIView in interface builder